# Creating program that adds & subtracts money when debit and credit buttons are pressed and operator error occurs

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

So, I'm trying to create a program to where a user inputs the money they want to deposit or credit and have it add & subtract money when the debit and credit buttons are pressed in a JFrame UI program.
However, when I try to add or subtract the money, it gives the following error codes

```
The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) JLabel, double 
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) JLabel, double
```

The lines in questions are:

```
Balance_Amount2 = Balance_Amount2 - d;
Balance_Amount2 = Balance_Amount2 + c;
```

I'll post the code below.

```
    Withdrawal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            String withdrawal = Withdrawal_Amount.getText();
            double d = Double.parseDouble(Withdrawal_Amount.getText());
            Balance_Amount2 = Balance_Amount2 - d;
                    

            Balance_Amount2.setText("$"+ String.valueOf(Balance_Amount));
            Balance_Amount2.setBounds(115, 107, 45, 20);
            Balance_Amount2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12)); 
        }
    });

    Deposit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // deposit++;
            // Balance_Amount.setText("BALANCE " );
            
            String deposit = Deposit_Amount.getText();
            double c = Double.parseDouble(Deposit_Amount.getText());
            Balance_Amount2 = Balance_Amount2 + c;

            Balance_Amount2.setText("$" + deposit);
            Balance_Amount2.setBounds(115, 107, 45, 20);
            Balance_Amount2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));     
        }
    });
```

Comment: The error is clear ,you are trying to substract or add a JLABEL type from/to a double,Balance_Amount2 is of type JLabel

Comment: Hi @karimfarhouti
Okay, thanks for letting me know.
I've tried to change it to deposit and withdrawal, but I get a very similar error, except the first type changes from a JLabel to a String; so I really don't know what to do.

Comment: if that String contains the amount you want to substract/add ,you can convert it into a double with Double.parseDouble(yourString) ,hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @karimfarhouti,
Okay, thanks for letting me know. I did a Double.parseDouble() for the String, but when I did it for the withdrawal and deposit Strings, it gave me an error code for the .getText() part saying "The method getText() is undefined for the type String", so I don't get what I'm doing wrong.
Also, sorry for not responding sooner.